# how to create various UIButtons with a for case in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

I have something like this...

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(00.0, 00.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [view addSubview:button];
}
```

It's possible to instantiate each button with his own id? For example button+i ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a numeric id to each button using the tag property:

```
button.tag = i;
```

You can then get the button instance afterwards with the code

```
[view viewWithTag:i];
```

provided you have added it to a view, like using [view addSubview:button].